# Remove transparency in bulk - GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency, png

I have 3,337 PNG images which all have a transparent background.

First of all, I don't know how to remove transparency...

Second of all, I want to do this with all 3,337 images at the same time.

I might as well kill two birds with one stone: 
How do I remove transparency from PNG images in GIMP in bulk (multiple items at the same time)?

Comment: Do you need to remove transparency as part of the layer or just remove the transparency of the background layer? Would bulk convert images from PNG to JPEG work in your situation?

Comment: Although GIMP has been specified I'd have thought ImageMagick would be better suited to this. E.g. `convert transparent.png -alpha off not_transparent.png`

Comment: @AndrewH Would that really work? If so, i. **MAKE IT AN ANSWER!** ii. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove transparency as part of the background you will want to batch/group convert the png file to jpg. You can find some online programs that will can do this by selecting your directory and choosing the export file.

Try a bulk image convertor http://sourceforge.net/projects/bulkimageconver/

For GIMP: GIMP has a batch mode, I am not experience in this feature but you can find a tutorial on their website and around the web. http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

However you don't necessarily need gimp to batch convert the images.

You can also create an action in Photoshop to do by creating a  save for web action and choose jpg as the file type. You can also do this in Lightroom by exporting your library as jpg.

Answer (score -2):

- PNG files support transparency
- JPEG files do not support transparency
- Changing your files to JPEG will remove the background transparency

**Step 1** -  Select all of your images,and open with  [this batch image convertor.](http://www.rentasoft.com/Image-Converter.asp)

**Step 2** - Convert to JPEG using the maximum quality setting.

You will now have a JPEG version of each image in the folder (with a white background).

*If you specifically want to use GIMP (batch mode) you will need a script to automate the process for you. You can save each image as a JPEG or else flatten each image to remove the alpha channel (transparency).*

Comment: This changes the file format type - and JPEG is even one of the lossy compressing ones.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! If you have any questions please let us know

Comment: This solution will work, but as a side effect the quality of the resulting image will be degraded due to the lossy JPEG compression.